# LockFree MultiConsumer/MultiProducer Queue

Tags: queue, lock-free

I've written a simple lock-free single-consumer/-producer queue.
It's supposed to work like this:

- at any time many consumers may read from it
- at any time multiple producers can write to it, added elements will
  be made available later
- after write modification is finished, we call "makePushedElementsAvailable()", so that consumers can read the newly added elements

.

```
template<typename T, int Size>
class MCMPQueue
{
public:
    MCMPQueue();
    bool tryPushLater(const T &element);
    bool tryPop(T &element);
    void makePushedElementsAvailable();
protected:
private:
    T elements[Size];
    std::atomic<int> iHead, iTail, iWrite;
};

template<typename T, int Size>
MCMPQueue<T, Size>::SCMPQueue() : iHead(0), iTail(0), iWrite(0)
{
}

template<typename T, int Size>
void MCMPQueue<T, Size>::makePushedElementsAvailable()
{
    iTail.store(iWrite.load());
}

template<typename T, int Size>
bool MCMPQueue<T, Size>::tryPop(T &element)
{
    int newIndex;
    int index;
    do {
        index = iHead.load();
        if (index == iTail.load())
            return false;
        newIndex = index + 1;
    } while (!iHead.compare_exchange_weak(index, newIndex));

    index = index % Size;
    element = elements[index];
    return true;
}

template<typename T, int Size>
bool MCMPQueue<T, Size>::tryPushLater(const T &element)
{
    int newIndex;
    int index;
    do {
        index = iWrite.load();
        if (index - iHead.load() >= Size)
            return false;
        newIndex = index + 1;
    } while (!iWrite.compare_exchange_weak(index, newIndex));

    index = index % Size;
    elements[index] = element;
    return true;
}
```

So far this seems to work fine, I'd like to have it checked by some others though please. Is there a simpler way than making the elements available after all updating has finished?

Thanks.

Comment: Asking to review functional code is off-topic on Stack Overflow and should be posted on [codereview.se] (please read their [help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help) before posting there).

Comment: Sorry, didn't know that. I'll crosspost, thanks.